# How do I put two elements in the same row with flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, polymer-1.0

```
  <template>
<style>
  .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .display {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85%;
  }
  .input {
    display: inline-block;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-self: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width:100%;
  }

</style>

<paper-drawer-panel>
  <paper-header-panel drawer>
    <paper-toolbar>
      <div>Application</div>
    </paper-toolbar>
  </paper-header-panel>
  <paper-header-panel main>
  <!--toolbar-->
    <paper-toolbar>
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
      <div class="container" tool layout horizontal>
        <div class="app-title" ><span>Cat Chat</span></div>

      <div class="account-icon">
        <iron-icon icon="account-circle"></iron-icon>
        <span>number of people</span>
        </div>
      </div>

    </paper-toolbar>

    <!--Main Content -->
    <div class="display" flex>
    </div>
      <div class="input" flex>
          <paper-input  label="Type message..." value={{input}}></paper-input>
          <paper-fab  icon="send" id="sendButton" on-tap="{{sendMyMessage}}"></paper-fab>
      </div>
  </paper-header-panel>
</paper-drawer-panel>
```

I am trying to line up the paper-input and the paper-button on the same row with the input going across most of the width and the button at the end.  Currently the button sits underneath the input.  How do I align them?[image]

Answer (score 5):

You are not applying `display: flex` to the `.input` selectors.

HTML :

```
 <div class="display"> 
 </div> 
 <div class="input">
     <paper-input  label="Type message..." value={{input}}></paper-input>
     <paper-fab  icon="send" id="sendButton" on-tap="{{sendMyMessage}}"></paper-fab>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-self: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    width:100%;
  }
```